# Regex for a string up to 20 chars long with a comma

Tags: regex

I need to define a regex for a string with the following requirements:

- Maximum 20 characters
- Must be in the form `Name,Surname`
- No numbers and special characters allowed (again, it's a name&surname)

I already tried something like `^[^1-9\?\*\.\?\$\^\_]{1,20}[,][^1-9\?\*\.\?\$\^\_\-]{1,20}$` but as you can find, it also matches a 40 chars long string.

How can I check for the whole string's maximum length and at the same time impose 1 comma inside of it and obviously not at the borders?

Thank you

Comment: Heh. I don't have time to prove it right now (the margin isn't big enough anyway) but I think this may not be possible with a regular expression.

Comment: I'd really suggest grabbing the free version of Expresso. (or pay for RegexBuddy). They're indispensable.

Comment: Assuming 20 is just an arbitrary number, I know people with 14 letters in their last name alone! You might want to bump it up if this is for a non-trivial project, or your customers might be upset when they find out their name is incompatible with the software!

Comment: @glowcoder: The requirement is not coming from my brain. I'll surely drop some words to who is responsible...

Comment: Please tell us, what kind of delimiter is between the names.

Comment: so does Name and Surname consist of at least 1 char? Or is can both be empty, or just one of them?

Comment: What is the delimiter between the names when some names contain spaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the regex:

```
^(?=[^,]+,[^,]+$)[a-zA-Z,]{1,20}$
```

[**Rubular Link**](http://www.rubular.com/r/H7FuwfTe6f)

Explanation:

```
^                : Start anchor
(?=[^,]+,[^,]+$) : Positive lookahead to ensure string has exactly one comma
                   surrounded by at least one non-comma character on both sides.
[a-zA-Z,]{1,20}  : Ensure entire string is of length max 20 and has only
                   letters and comma
$                : End anchor
```

Comment: Very good explanation. I tried it in http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx but it doesn't match "Name,Surname". What's wrong with my copy/paste?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using forward negative assertions:

```
^(?!.{21})[A-Za-z]+,[A-Za-z]+$
```

The regex contains two parts now, the actual definition, and a statement at the start, saying that from that point, there will not be 21 characters.

So for the definition as stated above, the regex becomes

```
^(?!.{21})[^1-9\?*\.\?\$\^_\,]+,[^1-9\?*\.\?\$\^_\,]+$
```

Comment: Seems close. I tried testing ",Surname" and it matches. Not the expected result but maybe if I replace * with + I can get something good

Comment: By the way, I currently accept you include only letters (names have spaces or single quotes like "D'Amato", accents and so on) and I'm really considering your answer for acceptation after performing a few tests

Comment: Yeah, I just took a simple set of chars to test with. Just substitute your set back, and it should work. And indeed, you want + instead of *, I'll edit that.

Comment: It should really be "^(?!.{21})[^1-9\?\*\.\?\$\^\_\,]+,[^1-9\?\*\.\?\$\^\_\,]+$", but if the assertion works, it beats my answer by a mile :-)

Comment: Editted it in, just to be clear. It works, at least, in languages which support forward assertions. In other languages your solution is the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

The obvious answer would be: Don't ask for name and surname in the same input field.

If you still want to do it: There's no easy way that I know of, but here is a possibility. To see the principle think your `[^1-9\?\*\.\?\$\^\_\,]` instead of `X` (I added he `\,` since it's kind of important :-)).

```
^(X{1},X{19})|(X{2},X{18})|...|(X{19},X{1})$
```

Quite ugly, but should work.

On a different note: You don't capture nearly all special characters with your exclusive range. But it's probably still better than an inclusive range.

Comment: Sorry, but the obvious answer is not an option for me, not being a designer ;) Anyway upvoted since the ugly solution at least **works**

Answer (score 0):

As I say, I think stated the way you have it, it's not matchable by a regular expression -- it's a pushdown language.

However, you could always split on ',' and match each substring, then total.

Comment: I considered the case that the whole pattern check is not matchable by regex only. Surely I could use the 40-chars regex PLUS some Java/Javascript validation logic. But I asked here to be sure there is no way.

Comment: Since you could even write out all possible strings, and put pipes in between, you can clearly create a regex...

Comment: Of course this can be done with regular expressions, at least what modern languages consider a "regular" expression. The tricky part is rather how do define what characters are valid in a name.

Comment: Sure is! Actually, facebook did not allowed spaces in names up until a year ago or something (and spaces in last names are actually quite common in the Netherlands)

Comment: Yeah, I should have seen that -- finite strings necessarily are a finite recognizer.  So [a-zA-Z .'],[a-zA-Z ]{1-19}+[a-zA-Z ]{2},[a-zA-Z .']{1-18} ... will work, eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I have you tried your example, but removing the

```
{1,20}
```

in the middle, leaving to try this:

```
^[[^1-9\?\*\.\?\$\^\_],[^1-9\?\*\.\?\$\^\_\-]]{1,20}$
```

Comment: both allow more than one?

remove the [] around the comma?

^[[^1-9\?\*\.\?\$\^\_],[^1-9\?\*\.\?\$\^\_\-]]{1,20}$

Comment: Sorry for the downvote Scott, but you are on a totally wrong track. []-brackets denote a character class, they are no substitution for ()-brackets. And if you use round brackets in your example you get totally different things like "a char followed by a comma followed by a char and that whole thing one to twenty times"

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful! I was looking at a tutorial while trying to come up with the answer and I think the tutorial is kind of confusing and missing some info, I remember doing regexp in college and thought I might be able to come up with an answer, oh well

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
[[a-zA-Z],[a-zA-Z]]{1,20}
```